# setInterval function not stopping when array length is reached

Tags: javascript

I have a simple setInterval function that is done inside of a for loop.  My goal is that I want the function to run on each position in the array, and once it reaches the end, I want it to stop.  However, this is not happening.  The timeout function is continuing to run infinitely.  Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong and what I need to do to fix this?

**JS**

```
Keyhole.bufferArray = [Keyhole.twoMileBuffer, Keyhole.fiveMileBuffer, Keyhole.tenMileBuffer, Keyhole.twentyFiveMileBuffer];

var ticker = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < Keyhole.bufferArray.length; i++){
    var populateServices = setInterval(function(){
        ++ticker;
        addBuffersToService(Keyhole, i);
        if(ticker >= Keyhole.bufferArray.length - 1){
            ticker = -1;
            clearInterval(populateServices);
        }
    }, 1000)
}

function addBuffersToService(Keyhole, index){
    console.log(Keyhole);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a for loop that is making an interval for every index of the array. You should not be using the for loop if you are looping over the array with the interval. **Remove the for loop.**

Comment: So, as asked, what do I need to do?

Comment: Remove the for loop

Comment: Although correct, being short with an answer is not friendly or helpful. (Just fyi)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you overwrite your interval handler in loop. I suggest you to kepp handlers in array and remove them according to iterator varialble:

```
var ticker = -1;
var populateServices = [];
for(var i = 0; i < Keyhole.bufferArray.length; i++){
    populateServices[ticker + 1] = setInterval(function(){
        ...
        clearInterval(populateServices[ticker + 1]);
        ticker = -1;
```

Note that array identifiers should be positive numbers so you should add `+1` inside handlers array.

And don't forget to set `ticker` to `-1` *after* `clearInterval` invokation.

Comment: the use of intervals inside a loop is **really** discouraged!

Comment: @AminJafari I don't argue about this. But to be 100% sure we need to see a better picture of what OP want to achieve. I've just provided a way to resolve his current problem.

Comment: you can encourage him to use a better solution to solve his problem IMHO